# ¿Cómo puedo conectar una app de escritorio de Tauri para que cargue correctamente el servidor local?

Tags: angular, localhost, electron, github-desktop

He realizado una app de escritorio con Tauri, implementado en un proyecto Angular, y al construir el distribuible, instalarlo y ejecutar el .exe, éste muestra que no se puede acceder al "tauri.localhost". ¿Cómo puedo conectar la app de escritorio para que ejecute correctamente la información del proyecto?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: Error de conexión de Tauri app de escritorio]

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al propio equipo de Tauri, he obtenido la respuesta:

Esto ocurre cuando instalas Tauri en un proyecto Angular. Tienes que cambiar "distPath" de "../dist" que viene por defecto a "../dist/nombreDeTuProyecto" y el .exe ya cargará perfectamente.